# Multiple kinect V2 devices in matlab

Tags: matlab, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-v2

Is it possible to detect and use more than one kinect V2 in matlab ?
(Usb traffic is no problem)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

NO you can NOT. But you can connect one Kinect v1 and one Kinect v2 together.If you connect both of them once and get the info with `imaqhwinfo`, you will see a output something like follows,

```
info = imaqhwinfo('kinect');    
info = 

       AdaptorDllName: '<matlabroot>\toolbox\imaq\supportpackages\kinectruntime\adaptor
                        \win64\mwkinectimaq.dll'
    AdaptorDllVersion: '5.0 (R2016a)'
          AdaptorName: 'kinect'
            DeviceIDs: {[1]  [2]  [3]  [4]}
           DeviceInfo: [1x2 struct]
```

Here `DeviceIDs` [1] is first Kinect sensor's Color Sensor , [2] is first Kinect sensor's depth Sensor, [3] is second Kinect sensor's Color Sensor and [4] is second Kinect sensor's depth Sensor